# Using Mokito to mock out an Akka Actor's log object

Tags: unit-testing, scala, mockito, akka, actor

I've tried a couple of things which seem to compile but throw NullPointer exceptions during unit testing so I'm wondering how I could potentially overcome the limitations in unit-testing.  I have a class which looks like this:

```
class LogWriter extends Actor{
  def receive{
    case x:Timing => log.info(x toString)
    case x:Event => log.info(x toString)
    case x:Any => log.warning("Improper message sent to LogWriter, %s".format(x toString))
  }
}
```

But attempting to unit test using Specs2 and the Mockito support with something along the lines of:

```
class LogWriterSpec extends Mokito with Specification{
  val mockedLog = mock[Logger]

  class MockedLogWriter extends LogWriter{
    @transient override val log = mockedLog
  }

  val writer = actorOf(new MockedLogWriter).start

  def testTiming = {
    val message = Timing("testTiming", 15 seconds)
    writer !! (message, 400)
    there was one(mockedLog).info(message toString)
  }

  def is = "A LogWriter" ^
    "should write a Timing message to log.info" ! testTiming ^
  end
}
```

while compiling results in the aforementioned `NullPointerException`:

```
[akka:event-driven:dispatcher:global-10] ERROR akka.actor.Actor$ - Problem
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at akka.util.Logger.warning_$qmark(Logging.scala:43)
    at akka.util.Logger.warning(Logging.scala:117)
```

I tried changing it to use some mixin trait which overrode the "log" object of the Akka `Logging` trait but the compiler didn't allow it.  The compiler reply was something along the lines of "we don't want you making an inadvertent mistake."  Ugh! I want that "mistake."

Anyone know of another way?  I'm not stuck to Mockito and welcome any suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

[Scalamock](http://borachio.com/) is a native Scala mock framework (among others, it allows mocking functions). You can find a complete example here:

http://www.paulbutcher.com/2011/11/scalamock-step-by-step/

Perhaps it will solve your problem.